# How to Mock CloudTable createQuery -AzureStorage

Tags: c#

This is the line of code that i am trying to mock.
var Entities = table.CreateQuery().Where(predicate).ToList();

Here table is a Cloud Table Object( Microsoft Azure Cosmos Table). I have mocked the table.

```
var cloudTableMock = new Mock<CloudTable>(new Uri("http://unittests.localhost.com/FakeTable"), null);
cloudTableMock.Setup(client => client.CreateQuery<TableEntity>()).Returns(new TableQuery<TableEntity>());
```

Facing the following error when the above statement is executed.

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

How can this be correctly mocked?